# Finding values of definite integral

Tags: integration

Hello i am new to integration and need some help on this simple question.

If $$\int_{0}^{6} f(x) dx = 18$$

find $I$ and $J$ where

$$I = \int_{0}^{3} f(2x) dx$$

and

$$J = \int_{0}^{\sqrt 6} xf(x^2) dx$$

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, you may take a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to format math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let $$K = \int_0^6 f(x)\ dx = 18$$

Now to find $I$, we use the substitution $$ u = 2x$$
So,
$$\frac{du}{dx} = 2 $$ 
and
$$dx = \frac{du}{2}$$

Also, when $x = 0, u = 0$ and when $x = 3, u = 6$

So, $I$ becomes: 
$$I = \int_0^6 \frac{f(u)\ du}{2} = \frac{1}{2}K = 9$$

As for J, we use the substitution $u = x^2$
So, 
$$\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$$ And 
$$dx = \frac{du}{2x}$$
When $x = 0\  ,\ u = 0$ and when $x = \sqrt{6}\ ,\ u = 6$
So, $J$ becomes: 
$$J = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^6 f(u) \ du = 9$$

We are safe to assume that $\int_0^6 f(u) \ du = I = 18$ because x and u are dummy variables.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to understand a more general approach to the problem. You’ve definitely worked with the Chain Rule in differentiation. (Both notations are fine.)

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}$$

$$(f\circ g)’(x) = f’(g(x))\cdot g’(x)$$

For instance, say you have $f(2x)$. You would use the Chain Rule to differentiate it because it is done with respect to $x$, not $2x$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(2x) = \frac{d}{d(2x)} f(2x)\cdot \frac{d}{d(2x)} 2x = 2\cdot\frac{d}{d(2x)} f(2x)$$

The reason knowing this would help is that integration is precisely the opposite of differentiation. One of the first techniques learned is integration by substitution, which is like a “Reverse Chain Rule.”

$$\int_{0}^{6} f(x) dx = 18$$

How would you solve for $I$ and $J$? You use this technique.

$$I = \int_{0}^{3} f(2x) dx$$

Here, you would want to rewrite the integrand in a way that you could use substitution.

Let $\color{blue}{u = 2x}$. That way, $\color{blue}{\frac{du}{dx} = 2}$. Thus, $\color{blue}{du = 2dx}$. You would have to cancel the $\color{blue}{2}$ with a $\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.

$$I = \int_{0}^{3} \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} f(\color{blue}{2x}) \color{blue}{2}dx$$

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{3} f(\color{blue}{u}) du$$

Recall $\color{blue}{u = 2x}$ and $\color{blue}{du = 2 dx}$.

$$\int_{0}^{3} f(\color{blue}{2x}) \color{blue}{2dx} = \int_{0}^{6} f(x) dx = 18$$

Simplify.

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 18 = 9$$

For the second part, you would carry out a similar process.

$$J = \int_{0}^{\sqrt 6} xf(x^2) dx$$

Let $\color{blue}{u = x^2}$. That way, $\color{blue}{\frac{du}{dx} = 2x}$. Thus, $\color{blue}{du = 2x dx}$. You already have the $x$, so just multiply the integrand by $\color{blue}{2}$ and $\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.

$$J = \int_{0}^{\sqrt 6} \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}f(x^2) \color{blue}{2}x dx$$

$$J = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt 6} f(\color{blue}{u}) du$$

Recall $\color{blue}{u = x^2}$ and $\color{blue}{du = 2x dx}$.

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt 6} f(\color{blue}{x^2}) \color{blue}{2x dx} = \int_{0}^{6} f(x) dx = 18$$

Simplify.

$$J = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 18 = 9$$